# WinForm Update during dragging using ReleaseCapture

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to update some graphical rendering based on the form's position as I drag the form with the mouse.
Since the form is border-less, I am using `ReleaseCapture` and `SendMessage` to move it.

However, I am not able to do my calls during the dragging operation.
I suppose it is possible to spawn a thread that runs until `SendMessage` returns a value, however I wanted to ask if there is a native method for this particular problem?

```
public void MoveWindow()
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    ....
}
```

Best regards

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  We can't see you doing it wrong.  Can't even tell what "not able to do my calls" could possibly mean.

Comment: @HansPassant Please see the edited post

Comment: @HansPassant "not able to do my calls" means that I want to do other method calls during the dragging operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events of form which raise at start, during and at the end of movement:

- Use [`Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx) event of form to do something during form movement.
- Use [`ResizeBegin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin.aspx) event of the form to do a job at start of movement.
- Use [`ResizeEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) event of the form to do a job at the end of movement.

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = this.Left/10 % 2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;
}
private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = this.Location.ToString(); 
}
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = this.Location.ToString();
}
```